# Map app for avoiding gravel roads

Tags: road-bike, maps, gravel

I use Google for mapping out long distance tours in areas I don't know. Often it takes me on gravel roads. I can't tell from the app that is not really road bike friendly till I get there. This can really mess up my plans (since I may I have to back track and go around adding hours to the day and getting to my camping destination.

That said - any favorite apps for bike travel - camping? Maps?  (I do have warm showers!  Love it for emergencies!)

Comment: There are OpenStreetMaps, but they are community-driven (although generally very good) and their offroad detail will vary depending on that community, and on where you are in the world. I offer this as a start-point, but I have no idea whether your current device can read them. T/he good news is that they're free, so it's probably worth investigating. Aside from that, there are apps like Orux Maps for Android, but this likes for you to be connected (there is a caching feature that I never worked out) and the maps available are quite limited. But again iirc it is free.

Comment: Saying where you're looking for and what device you're using will probably help.

Comment: @PeteH I think the problem here is on-road routes that are gravel. Open Street map would be a good tool for checking suspect roads, but I'm not sure if any of the cycle route planners based on it have the option to ignore gravel *roads*.

Comment: I use an iPhone (but my husband who travels with me uses Android)  Right now we are traveling in the US but plan to do Euope in a couple years.  this summer we will travel across Oregon (west to east), Iowa (back and forth across the state) and then the Sierra Cascades (From north OR to Central CA)   Needless to say, I am asking in general.  Last summer in Wisconsin, we were directed by Google maps to a 30 mile gravel road and did not know till we got there it was gravel.

Comment: I was looking at different routes over the Cascades for my across Oregon trip and Google Maps suggested past Timothy Lake and down thru Warm Springs reservation.  I used some forest service maps and could see about 50 miles were gravel and dirt - pretty slow going on a fully loaded road bike over a mountain pass!  I prefer pavement.  But when We are out in the middle of nowhere - the paper state maps usually have the state highways, and Google maps gives us some crazy and not bike friendly routes with the "bike" feature...  Does Open Street do across country?  I will check it out...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is off topic for bicycles.  You should ask on   http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ where this question is specifically on-topic.

Comment: The app can only be as good as the data it uses, which varies by country and supplier. First thing to check is the data source, and look up whats best in your country.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas everyone - this has been helpful!  *not sure how this is off topic for bicycles - it is about riding my bike.  I would think that finding good roads and good support apps are just as important as good bike equipment and riding techniques, etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Route planning and avoiding gravel/unpaved roads?](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/21293/route-planning-and-avoiding-gravel-unpaved-roads)

Answer (score 4):

There is no tool that I know of that solves your problem for you.

The way I solve the problem of finding out what a road is like, is to

- use Google maps to find a route.
- then use Street View to check the roads at important points. Of course, if the road is gravel, Street View is probably not available.
- if the route is not what I want, drag the route line to another road, and check that.

In addition (I didn't know about these and haven't tried them) there's [Gravel map](http://gravelmap.com/#@37.41920000000003,-122.05740000000004,11,hybrid) and similar sites that perhaps could be used to see where the gravel is, so you can avoid it.

Comment: Yeah - using street view is a good way of eyeballing a new route, I've done that to get a feel for just how navigable a "path" is, although even that isn't perfect. That site you link to seems very sparse.

Comment: Thanks - I did start using street view with Google maps and it helps from my home computer - not so much when I am out touring across the country and just using the phone.  We try to plan ahead, but sometimes we go where the road takes us - thanks for the ideas!

Comment: I was surprised just last weekend by a gravel road.  I see that road is marked on [Gravel Map](http://gravelmap.com/).  I'll be using that site from now on.  Thanks for the recommendation!

Comment: Hi @rclocher3. In a friendly way, I'd like to encourage you to vote more than you do, since I see from your profile that you don't vote much, even on your favourite SE sites. I looked because you took the trouble to comment that this post was useful, and unusually, hadn't voted. Then saw that you were new here. Each SE site has it's own character, created by the behaviour of its members. While voting is *completely* your option, it's the way SE sites measure our reputations. Please *don't* take my unsolicitied suggestion as a request to vote on *this* post :-)

Answer (score 3):

There is a tool I know of that solves your problem: [OsmAnd](http://osmand.net/) (available [for free on F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdfilter=OSMAnd&fdid=net.osmand.plus), paid versions on Android Play Store + iOS App Store).

If the region has decent coverage with properly mapped [highway types](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Map_Features#Highway), the app's offline routing offers a bicycle mode + the **option to avoid unpaved roads**. Whether the data coverage is good enough in the region can be visually checked on [openstreetmap.org](http://www.openstreetmap.org/) by zooming in. In the default style, **blue dashed** cycle ways are paved, while **brown dashed** tracks are unpaved.

I can only confirm the routing feature for Android, though. The OsmAnd homepage states as of Jun'16:

> Navigation (Android only)

Comment: Nice to hear there's *something*!

Comment: Also, if the data coverage is poor in your area, then you should help improve it for the next person!  It's pretty easy to update OSM using the in-browser editor on openstreetmap.org.

Answer (score -1):

I personally use MapMyRide by Under Armour. It can track routes as you just bike along, or you can plan them out first. It also has community routes that others have completed.

When planning out your route, it tells you elevation and can also indicate gravel or other materials (dirt).

Comment: Where is the gravel indicator on MapMyRide? I just set a route onto a road I know is gravel. There was no indication that it went from asphalt to gravel.

Comment: Hit map options and select "Terrain". I know for sure this is on desktop version but it takes some finding in the app

Comment: Screenshots and more description would seem to be required for this to be a useful answer. Any time you say "not obvious" you should ideally make it obvious in your answer. That way people saying "this is wrong" because they missed it will be inclined to follow your instructions and discover that you're correct! Plus, obviously, you're helping people which is the whole point :)

Comment: I do use MapMyRide - great to know there are other views.  i can't tell the gravel with the "terrain" view for some reason (I did check it out on a road i know is gravel)  I did find the US topo view will show gravel.  Thanks for the ideas.